# Infer an schema to DataFrame pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, load

I have seen many solutions for scala or other kind of files. But how to infer the schema to a load DataFrame, a csv file, in python with pyspark.

```
df = spark.read.csv('dataset.csv')
```

If I check the schema all columns are string. I could change column by column but I suposse there is a much better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I leave it here in the case someone have the same doubt. Where there is written column you should put the name of the column.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("column1", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("column2", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("column3", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("column4", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
)
```

The fastest way is to inferSchema and set the columns type. I suposse that it can make mistakes, check it after creating DataFrame

```
df = spark.read.csv('dataset.csv',  inferSchema = True)
```